# Función long con if

Tags: java, condiciones

He hecho una función que crea un número generado aleatoriamente, y quiero hacer otra función que reciba ese número, y mediante if retorne un valor u otro, dependiendo del número aleatorio que se haya generado. Pero aunque ponga el return dentro de los if necesito un return fuera de ellos. Y no sé cómo quitar el error.
Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
public static long numero1(long numero2)
{
    if (numero2 < 10)
    {
        return numero2;
    }

    if (numero2 == 11)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (numero2 == 10)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Estás sufriendo este error ya que en mucho lenguajes (como java, C++ y demás) un método o función que devuelve un valor debe tener un "return" en cualquier posible flujo de control (es decir, que se deberá poder alcanzar siempre un "return" independientemente de qué IFs, WHILEs y demás se hayan activado). Por lo que veo en tu código para los número mayores de 11 no existe sentencia de return (esto es lo que está causando tu problema). Puede ser que tu código no vaya a recibir nunca enteros mayores de 11, pero eso JAVA no lo sabe, por tanto deberías modificar tu código para que se alcanze un "r

Answer (score 1):

El problema con tu código es que no abarcas todos los posibles valores que puede tener la variable `numero2`.
Según tu algoritmo abarcas 3 posibles casos:
caso 1:  `numero2`<10
caso 2: `numero2`=10
caso 3: `numero2`=11
Pero que va pasar cuando `numero2` sea diferente de los casos anteriores, no estás tomando en cuenta esto, por lo tanto el IDE te mostrará un error porque no sabe que valor retornar.
La solución puede ser agregar un caso default.

```
public static long numero1(long numero2){ 
        if (numero2 < 10){
            return numero2;            
        }
        if (numero2 == 11){
            return 0;            
        }
        if (numero2 == 10){
            return 1;            
        }
        //agregamos un caso default
        else{
            return 999;
        }        
 }
```

Si bien es cierto el código anterior puede ser una solución, no es del todo correcto debido a que los casos planteados son **CONJUNTOS DISJUNTOS**, quiere decir si no se cumple el caso 1, se cumple el caso 2, sino el caso 3, sino el caso default.
La solución es trabajar con `if else`, además debe tener un único return, para ello vamos crear una variable local al cual se va asignar el valor que retornará el método.

```
public static long numero2(long numero2)
    {   
        long devolver;
        
        if (numero2 < 10){
            devolver=numero2;            
        }else if (numero2 == 11){
            devolver=0;                
        }else if (numero2 == 10){                
            devolver=1;
        }else{                    
            devolver=999;//no ocurre ninguna de las anteriores
        }    
        return devolver;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es que ese código no garantiza que se devuelva algo: Imagina que el número que pasas como parámetro es 12:

```java
public static long numero1(long numero2)
{
    if (numero2 < 10) // 12 no es menor que 10
    {
        return numero2;
    }

    if (numero2 == 11) //12 no es 11
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (numero2 == 10) //12 no es 10
    {
        return 1;
    }
    //hemos llegado aquí y no hay return!
}
```

La solución más sencilla para evitar estos problemas es tener un único return y un valor "por defecto":

```java
public static long numero1(long numero2) {
    long resultado = 9999; // valor por defecto, en caso de que ninguna condición se cumpla

    if (numero2 < 10) {
        resultado = numero2;
    } else if (numero2 == 11) {
        resultado = 0;
    } else if (numero2 == 10) {
        resultado = 1;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```